Aplicación Flask (Python) No graba en SQL Server
Mi código es el siguiente:
    conn = pyodbc.connect(stConexion)
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    try:
        # Iniciar una transacción
        cursor.execute("BEGIN TRANSACTION;")

        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM PAR_USUARIOS")
        Usuarios = cursor.fetchall()
        print(Usuarios)
        
        # Realizar algunas operaciones
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO PAR_USUARIOS VALUES ('Juan','987Juan987')")
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO PAR_USUARIOS VALUES ('Maria','123Maria123')")
        
        # Confirmar la transacción
        cursor.execute("COMMIT TRANSACTION;")
        print("Transacción completada con éxito.")
    except Exception as e:
        # Si ocurre un error, revertir la transacción
        cursor.execute("ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;")
        print("Error en la transacción:", e)
    finally:
        # Cerrar la conexión
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()

El profiler de SQL Server me muestra todas las instrucciones desde el begin transaction hasta el commit transaction.
El SELECT funciona correctamente, y trae datos, con lo cual me aseguro que el ConectionString está correcto.
No hay errores de ejecución.
La ejecución de este script termina con "Transacción completada con éxito."
Pero al hacer el SELECT, desde el Management a la tabla PAR_USUARIOS, los datos no están.
Qué puede estar pasando...???
Muchas Gracias
